# Return department of user's manager?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, multiple-users

I'm trying to gather some information for a clean-up effort on my company's vendor accounts.  One of the bits we want is "what department is their *manager* in?"

My little script right now will return several other pieces of info, and I can conceptualize how you would need to collect the "manager" attribute for each user, then for THAT user, look at the "department" attribute.  But I can't quite see how to proceed.

Here's what I've got.  This works but doesn't include the department of the user's manager:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'ou=Vendors,ou=Users,dc=corporate,dc=coolguys,dc=org' -Properties GivenName, Surname, Company, Title, Manager, EmailAddress |
     select GivenName, Surname, Company, Title, Manager, EmailAddress |
     Out-GridView
```

Just as a wild hail-Mary I tried returning "manager.department" like it was a value in a variable, but of course PS just scoffed at my ineptitude.  Do I need to set a variable that contains all the search results and then use a `foreach` loop to say "for each user's manager, find that user's department"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`department` is a property of a user object. The `manager` property, however, doesn't contain a user object, but a distinguished name. To get the desired property you need to retrieve the user object corresponding to the `manager` property and expand its `department` property.

```
... | Select-Object GivenName, Surname, Company, Title, Manager, EmailAddress,
  @{n='ManagerDepartment';e={Get-ADUser $_.Manager -Properties department |
     Select-Object -Expand department}} | ...
```